# react native pass parameter through json

Tags: reactjs, json, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

1

I am creating a student app in react native using a student api.

The login api gives me email using it . I would only like to display the all student info that is email equal to the i need to send to mysql through json .

**i want to send parameter through json and wany mysql query to recieve email**

```
class ShowStudentListActivity extends Component {

static navigationOptions ={title: 'SecondActivity',};

constructor(props) {

     super(props)

     this.state={

      IdHolder : '',
      NameHolder : '',
      EmailHolder : '',
      PasswordHolder : '',
      ParentIdHolder : ''

     }
  
   }

componentDidMount(){// const text = this.props.route.params.Email//const myArr = JSON.parse(text);}ShowStudentRecord = () =>{fetch('http://30c6-197-157-245-18.ngrok.io/noder/ShowAllStudentsList1.php', {method: 'POST',headers: {'Accept': 'application/json','Content-Type': 'application/json',},body: JSON.stringify({

        // Getting the id.
        
        email:"m3.adam@telesom.com"
      })
     
    }).then((response) => response.text())
          .then((responseJson) => {

            this.setState({

              IdHolder : responseJson[0].id,
              NameHolder : responseJson[0].name,
              EmailHolder : responseJson[0].email,
              PasswordHolder : responseJson[0].password,
              ParentIdHolder : responseJson[0].parent_id

            })
            
          }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });
     
        }

render(){return(<View style = { styles.MainContainer }>

      <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'column'}} >
     
       <Text style={styles.textViewContainer} > {'id = ' + this.state.IdHolder} </Text>

       <Text style={styles.textViewContainer} > {'Name = ' + this.state.NameHolder} </Text>

       <Text style={styles.textViewContainer} > {'Email = ' + this.state.EmailHolder} </Text>

       <Text style={styles.textViewContainer} > {'Password = ' + this.state.PasswordHolder} </Text>

       <Text style={styles.textViewContainer} > {'Parent ID = ' + this.state.ParentIdHolder} </Text>

      </View>
      <View style = { styles.MainContainer }>

        <Text style = {styles.TextComponentStyle}> { this.props.route.params.Email} </Text>

        <Button title="Click here to Logout" onPress={ () => goBack(null) } />

     </View>

    </View>
  );

}}
```

i tried
email:{email :this.props.route.params.Email}

or
email:this.props.route.params.Email

or

email:"m3.adam@telesom.com"

Answer (score 0):

```
componentDidMount(){
const text = this.props.route.params.Email
const myArr = JSON.parse(text);}
ShowStudentRecord = () =>{
fetch('http://30c6-197-157-245-18.ngrok.io/noder/ShowAllStudentsList1.php', {method: 'POST',headers: {'Accept': 'application/json','Content-Type': 'application/json',},body: JSON.stringify({

        // Getting the id.
        
        //email:"m3.adam@telesom.com",
         email: text,
        emailBody: myArr,
        emailSubject: "Test Mail"
      })
     
    }).then((response) => response.text())
          .then((responseJson) => {
            Linking.openURL('mailto:text?subject=emailSubject&body=myArr');
                            
            this.setState({

              IdHolder : responseJson[0].id,
              NameHolder : responseJson[0].name,
              EmailHolder : responseJson[0].email,
              PasswordHolder : responseJson[0].password,
              ParentIdHolder : responseJson[0].parent_id

            })
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).